# Popup Close button is not working in internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

This script fails in internet explorer its get popup but close button not working and its working in firefox and google chrome fine.

```
#note {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 101;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #fde073;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2.5;
    overflow: hidden; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 5px black;
    box-shadow:         0 0 5px black;
}


<div id="note">
    You smell good. <a id="close">[close]</a>
<script>
 close = document.getElementById("close");
 close.addEventListener('click', function() {
   note = document.getElementById("note");
   note.style.display = 'none';
 }, false);
</script></div>
```

Comment: is this working in other browsers?

Comment: Working in Firefox and Chrome according to user.

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer are you testing in?

Comment: I think its because of internet explorer setting. Any pop message from other website also cant close ex.[http://css-tricks.com/examples/PopFromTopMessage/]

Answer (score 2):

change close variable, close is a event not variable.

```
<script>
 divclose = document.getElementById("close");
 divclose.addEventListener('click', function() {
   note = document.getElementById("note");
   note.style.display = 'none';
 }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Now popup window closing fine.

Comment: I have created one home page for my department that web page script access from normal office server but getting problem while access web page from server but working fine when open from my computer.Its need any special server??

Comment: check the apache server Version or PHP version. did you used any php code?

Comment: No its just simple home page for my department i have that script in normal server which we using for documents. your script is working fine when open form my local driver but cant close notification when open from that server.

Answer (score 1):

javascript is not cross browser supported, use jQuery instead

```
 $("#close").on('click', function() {
   $("#note").hide();
 });
```